# how to install a python package to windows?

Tags: python, windows, installation

I would like to install a python package to windows. I have tried to run setup.py install  on command prompt but it returned an error:
could not create 'C:\Program Files\Python...': access is denied.
Please, help.
Špela

Answer (score 2):

My first question would be, do you have administration rights when you try to run setup.py?

Comment: How do you know if you have them?

Comment: Well, I would start there.  Also I would fix the tags for this question, as it has nothing to do with asp.net.  Many people only view questions for tags they're familiar with.

Comment: Yes I noticed the thing with tags. I didn't really know what the tag is supposed to be so I just picked the one that has been suggested:)

Comment: Which version of windows are you running?  And is this a personal computer or one managed/owned by someone else?

Comment: Windows 7. It is my personal computer but I haven't install Windows so I don't have a password. But my account is the only one the computer so it might be administrator account.

Comment: ok I finally managed to do it. You were right, administration rights was the problem. Thank you for your help.